Trouble with shared state updates between threads using Arc and Mutex in Rust
I'm working on a Rust application where I need to manage shared state between two threads using Arc and Mutex. The application has a Node struct that holds some data, and I'm trying to update this data in one thread and read it in another. However, I'm facing an issue where updates made in the handle_client thread are not visible in the do_broadcast thread. I suspect this might be due to the way I'm handling locking, but I'm not sure how to resolve it.
Here's a simplified version of my code:
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Message<P> {
    // fields omitted for brevity
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node {
    msg_id: usize,
    sum: usize,
    log: HashMap<String, usize>,
    node_id: String,
    node_ids: Vec<String>,
}

impl Node {
    fn step(&mut self, input: Message<Payload>, output: &mut io::StdoutLock) -> anyhow::Result<()> {
        // implementation details
    }

    fn broadcast(&mut self, output: &mut io::StdoutLock) {
        // implementation details
    }
}

fn main() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    let node = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Node {
        msg_id: 0,
        sum: 0,
        log: HashMap::new(),
        node_id: "node1".to_string(),
        node_ids: vec!["node2".to_string()],
    }));

    let _node = node.clone();

    let handle_client = thread::spawn(move || {
        let stdin = io::stdin().lock();
        let inputs = serde_json::Deserializer::from_reader(stdin).into_iter::<Message<Payload>>();
        let mut stdout = io::stdout().lock();

        for input in inputs {
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1));
            let input = input.context("cannot deserialize the input message").unwrap();
            _node.lock().unwrap().step(input, &mut stdout).unwrap();
        }
    });

    let _node = node.clone();

    let do_broadcast = thread::spawn(move || loop {
        let mut stdout = io::stdout().lock();
        _node.lock().unwrap().broadcast(&mut stdout);
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(100));
    });

    handle_client.join().unwrap();
    do_broadcast.join().unwrap();

    Ok(())
}

In the handle_client thread, I'm processing user input and updating the Node instance. In the do_broadcast thread, I'm trying to read the updated values to broadcast them. However, the updates are not visible in the do_broadcast thread.
What could be causing this issue, and how can I ensure that the do_broadcast thread sees the updates made by the handle_client thread?
Additional Information:
I attempted a workaround by modifying the loop in the handle_client thread as follows:
for input in inputs {
    thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1));
    let input = input.context("cannot deserialize the input message").unwrap();
    _node.lock().unwrap().step(input, &mut stdout).unwrap();
    break;  // Breaking after the first input
}

Adding break after processing the first input resolves the issue, and the do_broadcast thread is able to see the updated values. However, this solution is not viable for my application because I need to continuously listen for user input without breaking out of the loop.
How can I modify my code to continuously process user input in the handle_client thread while ensuring that updates are visible in the do_broadcast thread?
Github Link of code

Please post a Minimal Reproducible Example in the question itself. External links do no suffice.

My initial suspicion would be the scoping of your mutex locks; try with them inside braces.  You could also verify that in a debugger to see what the threads are doing.

@trojanfoe If they are in one statement, as shown here, it's not the problem.

You're locking stdout for the full loop in the handle_client thread, you should lock it only when you need it.

looks to me like both threads are trying to lock stdout and never yield it to eachother. That is a sort of explicit deadlock situation.
